# vector to pointer conversion

Tags: c++, api, vector, struct

I need to call an API function which needs a struct-pointer as a parameter.

lets say its this struct

```
struct SomeObject{
   double a;
   double b;
}
```

and this function to call: `func(SomeObject*)`

The problem here is that I only have access to data as a custom struct but the same structure like SomeObject given as an vector.

```
struct CustomObject{
    double a;
    double b;
}
```

And the compiler is throwing errors because they are different parameters. `cannot convert 'std::vector<CustomObject>' to 'SomeObect*' in argument passing`. I tried already to pass the CustomObject as a pointer but its of course still a different Object.

Is there any chance to get this working what I am trying to do? And what could be a possible approach?

Comment: No signatures & thanks & such on Stackoverflow, please.

Comment: If you only pass a pointer to an array, how does the function figure out the size of the array?

Comment: One of the arguments is also an int with the number to indicate the ammount the objects. The sample struct is just to simplify the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a `std::vector` to a function that expects a pointer. If the function expects a pointer to an array, then you can get that pointer using `std::vector::data`

Now, that leaves us with the problem that the vector contains objects of a wrong type. The pointer returned by `std::vector::data` will be of type `CustomObject*` while you need `SomeObject*`. They're unrelated, but identical types and luckily, [standard layout types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType). As long as those two requirements hold, that gives us the guarantee that the types have the same representation. Therefore, we can simply cast the pointer with [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

```
func(reinterpret_cast<SomeObject *>(vec.data()));
```

> The compiler is now showing 'cast away qualifiers'. It seems to have a problem with because CustomObject is currently a const.

I take that to mean that the vector is `const`, or it's a vector of `const` objects. In that case you *shouldn't* pass it's data to a function that takes a pointer to non-`const`. But if you know that the function will not modify the objects, despite taking a pointer to non-const, and you want to get rid of the compiler warning, then you must cast the constness away explicitly, using [const_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast).

Comment: It seems to work. The compiler is now showing 'cast away qualifiers'. It seems to have a problem because CustomObject is currently a const.

Comment: It worked with func(reinterpret_cast<SomeObject*> (const_cast<CustomObejct*>(vec.data())))

Comment: Well there are some informations missing. I need to use Apchae Thrift to get boths sides of the API working. Apache Thift cant handle (afaik) pointers of structures. Therefore i need to use list<...>. C++ is getting the list<...> as a 'const std:vector' and the API can only use a simple pointer of the SomeObject besides some other primitive pramateters. It feels like the inception-movie :D

Answer (score 1):

`reinterpret_cast` might have 'solved' the problem, but has made your code incredibly brittle. I'd really not recommend that approach.

Instead I'd manually construct a `SomeObject` from the `CustomObject`:

```
SomeObject x;
x.a = myCustomObj.a;
x.b = myCustomObj.b;

func(&x);
```

This also avoids the `const` issue. Don't even *think* about optimizations or efficiency at this stage. YAGNI.

Comment: Is it really that simple? What about when there are plenty of myCustomObjs?

Comment: @wurmi You'd need this for each call to `func`, of course. If you have several of those, then just make a wrapper function `void myFunc(const CustomObject &myCustomObj) {...}` with the code as above.

Answer (score -1):

```
func((SomeObject *)&obj[0]);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.